# What is the correct PM2 command to serve a js file inside the webpack production build directory?

Tags: node.js, webpack, pm2

Suppose I have used webpack to bundle my codes into a directory named `dist`.

I did that with the command `npm run build`.

Here is my script section in `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ./test/test*.js --recursive --compilers js:babel-core/register",
    "start": "node server",
    "build": "rimraf dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "eslint": "eslint .",
    "jscs": "jscs ."
},
```

If I want to use PM2 to start my app in production, which is named **bundle.js**, How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `process.json` file, and specify there the file you need to run explicitly:

```
{
  apps : [{
    name        : "server",
    script      : "./dist/bundle.js",
    watch       : true,
    env: {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
    },
    env_production : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What if the bundle file name contains a random number? I just found that the file generated by `npm run build` has a random number and letters combination in its name. Something like `main-2d4451c6f63d1577504f.min.js`.

Comment: Does filename look like this `bundle.a76gs0ad5dh45sdh9aa.js`?

Comment: It is actually **main-2d4451c6f63d1577504f.min.js**, the random number and letters are generated by hash. I thought there is a universal solution for all kinds of filenames so I said it is bundle.js at the beginning.

Comment: Ok, there isn't a big difference. Can you please show your webpack configs?

Comment: Sure. The webpack configuration is exactly the same as this one: https://github.com/christianalfoni/webpack-express-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.production.config.js

Comment: Well, if there would be many files in the *dist* directory like *main-[hash].min.js*, which one do you want pm2 to run? The last one created?

Comment: There is only one js file in the dist directory. Not sure what you mean. If I rerun `npm run build` it will ditch the dist directory and recreate directory and the files with the same filename.

Comment: Ok, than what's the meaning of the hash in the filename? On client side it's used in order to force browser to ignore last bundle and load new one ignoring cache in such a way. Not sure there is a sense to do it with node apps. I would recommend to change ` filename: '[name]-[hash].min.js'`  to ` filename: '[name]-.min.js'  in webpack configs and have a static filename.